# How to print the first character of a table element?

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

Supose you have the following table:

```
mytable = {"firstelement", "secondelement", "thirdelement" }

print (mytable [1]) 
==> firstelement
```

How do i make it print only the "f" from the "firstelement" ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple string operation:

```
print(mytable[1]:sub(1,1))
```

more info can be found in the [Lua Users string library tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) or [String manipulation in the Lua Reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4)

Answer (score 0):

`print( mytable[1]:sub(1, 1) )`